# transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug FAILED issue with Gradle

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

I am fairly new at Android development and have been struggling to get a working build of an app I am working on.

I receive the following error after a build with Gradle:

> :app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>
>   > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   >     android/support/v4/print/PrintHelper$1.class

I (think) I narrowed the issue down to multiple libraries using the same 'support-v4' module, but I'm not sure. I can provide more details. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by deleting .jar files that were duplicates.

Comment: I am facing same issue. Can you please explain solution in more detail? Which .jar file was duplicated and need to delete?

Comment: It's been quite a while since I've experienced the issue. That specific project was importing libraries in .jar files, which were deprecated. If you're importing jar files, I suggest compiling against maven instead. If not, checking your dependencies with the following command: `$ ./gradlew app:dependencies`

Review any potential duplicates and remove them from your project then run `$ ./gradlew clean assemble`