# how can i solve Duplicate class com.android.volley.AuthFailureError found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar

Tags: android

this is the error

```
Duplicate class com.android.volley.AuthFailureError found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.BuildConfig found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.Cache found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.Cache$Entry found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.CacheDispatcher found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.CacheDispatcher$1 found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.DefaultRetryPolicy found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$1 found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.Network found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.NetworkError found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.NetworkResponse found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.NoConnectionError found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.ParseError found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.Request found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.Request$1 found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.Request$Method found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.Request$Priority found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.RequestQueue found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.RequestQueue$1 found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.RequestQueue$RequestFilter found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.Response found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.Response$ErrorListener found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.Response$Listener found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.ResponseDelivery found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.RetryPolicy found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.ServerError found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.TimeoutError found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.VolleyError found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.VolleyLog found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.VolleyLog$MarkerLog found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.VolleyLog$MarkerLog$Marker found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.AndroidAuthenticator found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.Authenticator found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.ByteArrayPool found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.ByteArrayPool$1 found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.ClearCacheRequest found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache$CacheHeader found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache$CountingInputStream found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack$HttpPatch found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpHeaderParser found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpStack found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack$UrlRewriter found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader$1 found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader$2 found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader$3 found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader$4 found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader$BatchedImageRequest found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader$ImageCache found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader$ImageContainer found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader$ImageListener found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageRequest found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonArrayRequest found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonRequest found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView$1 found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView$1$1 found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.NoCache found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.PoolingByteArrayOutputStream found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.RequestFuture found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)
Duplicate class com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley found in modules jetified-volley-1.1.1-runtime.jar (com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1) and volley.jar (volley.jar)

Go to the documentation to learn how to Fix dependency resolution errors.
```

This is my build.gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    android {
        signingConfigs {
            config {
                keyAlias 'pimpimp'
                keyPassword '123456'
                storeFile file('D:/gayatri_esw_workspace/es_Gayatri_Projects/PimPim/Keystore/pimpimp.jks')
                storePassword '123456'
            }
        }
        compileSdkVersion 29
        buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.pimpimp.passenger"
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 29
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            multiDexEnabled true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "5g"
            jumboMode = true
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                shrinkResources false
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }

            signingConfigs {
                release {
                    storeFile file("D:/gayatri_esw_workspace/es_Gayatri_Projects/PimPim/Keystore/pimpimp.jks")
                    storePassword "123456"
                    keyAlias "pimpimp"
                    keyPassword "123456"
                }
            }


        }
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libcardioDecider.so'
            exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libcardioRecognizer.so'
            exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libcardioRecognizer_tegra2.so'
            exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libopencv_core.so'
            exclude 'lib/arm64-v8a/libopencv_imgproc.so'
            exclude 'lib/armeabi/libcardioDecider.so'
            exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libcardioDecider.so'
            exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libcardioRecognizer.so'
            exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libcardioRecognizer_tegra2.so'
            exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_core.so'
            exclude 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libopencv_imgproc.so'
            exclude 'lib/mips/libcardioDecider.so'
            exclude 'lib/x86/libcardioDecider.so'
            exclude 'lib/x86/libcardioRecognizer.so'
            exclude 'lib/x86/libcardioRecognizer_tegra2.so'
            exclude 'lib/x86/libopencv_core.so'
            exclude 'lib/x86/libopencv_imgproc.so'
            exclude 'lib/x86_64/libcardioDecider.so'
            exclude 'lib/x86_64/libcardioRecognizer.so'
            exclude 'lib/x86_64/libcardioRecognizer_tegra2.so'
            exclude 'lib/x86_64/libopencv_core.so'
            exclude 'lib/x86_64/libopencv_imgproc.so'


            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE' // will not include NOTICE file
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE' // will not include LICENSE file
            // as noted by @Vishnuvathsan you may also need to include
            // variations on the file name. It depends on your dependencies.
            // Some other common variations on notice and license file names
            exclude 'META-INF/notice'
            exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/license'
            exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'

        }
        productFlavors {
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility = 1.8
            targetCompatibility = 1.8
        }

    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()

        maven {
            url "https://mint.splunk.com/gradle/"
        }

        /* maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }*/


    }
    dependencies {

        implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
          // compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'

        //implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:27.1.1
        implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.2.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:16.0.0'

      //  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
      //  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
       // implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm-auth:10.2.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.libraries.places:places:2.1.0'
        implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.12.1'
        //    compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.13.3'
        implementation 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
        implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.2.0'
        implementation 'com.splunk.mint:mint:5.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
        implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
        implementation 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
        implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:2.1.0'
        implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
        //java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: out == null
        implementation 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0'
        implementation 'com.pubnub:pubnub:4.0.14'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:19.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.2'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.0'
        //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'


        //    compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.13.3'
        implementation files('libs/PayPalAndroidSDK.jar')
    }
```

Comment: I would look into the solutions listed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36990054/android-studio-resolving-duplicate-classes.

Some of your dependencies are conflicting with each other. The link about shows possible solutions.

Answer (score -1):

try removing this line:

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
```