# Android Studio - after doing upgrade of gradle ':app:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses' task failed

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle

After some update when try to build APK I get errors bellow.
Tried few times times gradlew clean, no success.
Did Invalidate Caches/Restart..., same result.
Any idea?

My build.gradle looks like here

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {

    compileSdkVersion 29

    buildToolsVersion '29.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ro.notnull.bubblesinline"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 8
        versionName "1.7.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            debuggable false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            shrinkResources true
        }
        debug {
            //buildConfigField("String", "BUILD_TIME", "\"0\"")
            debuggable true
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

}

dependencies {
    def acraVersion = '5.1.3'
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    /*androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })*/
    //compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation "androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    //implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0'
    //implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
    //debugImplementation "ch.acra:acra-mail:$acraVersion"
    // implementation "ch.acra:acra-mail:$acraVersion"
    //implementation "ch.acra:acra-toast:$acraVersion"
    //implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    //testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations-java5:15.0'
}
```

Execution failed for task ':app:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:releaseRuntimeClasspath'.
> Failed to transform vectordrawable-animated-1.1.0.aar (androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable-animated:1.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for EnumerateClassesTransform: C:\Users\marce.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\a8329ab02c0eec2f11b88dbefe816a58\vectordrawable-animated-1.1.0-runtime.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform vectordrawable-1.1.0.aar (androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for EnumerateClassesTransform: C:\Users\marce.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\15e0920bb536af9b5fe80c92ab0cb8a4\vectordrawable-1.1.0-runtime.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform vectordrawable-1.1.0.aar (androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for EnumerateClassesTransform: C:\Users\marce.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\15e0920bb536af9b5fe80c92ab0cb8a4\vectordrawable-1.1.0-runtime.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform cursoradapter-1.0.0.aar (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for EnumerateClassesTransform: C:\Users\marce.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\9a95edf3f5cc6d9e59493443505931b8\cursoradapter-1.0.0-runtime.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform cursoradapter-1.0.0.aar (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for EnumerateClassesTransform: C:\Users\marce.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\9a95edf3f5cc6d9e59493443505931b8\cursoradapter-1.0.0-runtime.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform interpolator-1.0.0.aar (androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for EnumerateClassesTransform: C:\Users\marce.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\707397966303cc690504f71917c7b9bb\interpolator-1.0.0-runtime.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform interpolator-1.0.0.aar (androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for EnumerateClassesTransform: C:\Users\marce.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\707397966303cc690504f71917c7b9bb\interpolator-1.0.0-runtime.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform interpolator-1.0.0.aar (androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for EnumerateClassesTransform: C:\Users\marce.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\707397966303cc690504f71917c7b9bb\interpolator-1.0.0-runtime.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform interpolator-1.0.0.aar (androidx.interpolator:interpolator:1.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for EnumerateClassesTransform: C:\Users\marce.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\707397966303cc690504f71917c7b9bb\interpolator-1.0.0-runtime.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform versionedparcelable-1.1.0.aar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for EnumerateClassesTransform: C:\Users\marce.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\832ba580bd4051a06bf7812644f759bd\versionedparcelable-1.1.0-runtime.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform versionedparcelable-1.1.0.aar (androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for EnumerateClassesTransform: C:\Users\marce.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\832ba580bd4051a06bf7812644f759bd\versionedparcelable-1.1.0-runtime.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform collection-1.1.0.jar (androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for EnumerateClassesTransform: C:\Users\marce.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.collection\collection\1.1.0\1f27220b47669781457de0d600849a5de0e89909\collection-1.1.0.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform documentfile-1.0.0.aar (androidx.documentfile:documentfile:1.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for EnumerateClassesTransform: C:\Users\marce.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\035a65c630c35c5d7db5888f5597f3bd\documentfile-1.0.0-runtime.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform localbroadcastmanager-1.0.0.aar (androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for EnumerateClassesTransform: C:\Users\marce.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\ecf681c70488063c13a663f45c33cc7c\localbroadcastmanager-1.0.0-runtime.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform print-1.0.0.aar (androidx.print:print:1.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for EnumerateClassesTransform: C:\Users\marce.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\1733e4948d0824aca25b28a5df1633bc\print-1.0.0-runtime.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform lifecycle-viewmodel-2.1.0.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for EnumerateClassesTransform: C:\Users\marce.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\0f281f39f7f929407d14ee241c94da2d\lifecycle-viewmodel-2.1.0-runtime.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform lifecycle-viewmodel-2.1.0.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for EnumerateClassesTransform: C:\Users\marce.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\0f281f39f7f929407d14ee241c94da2d\lifecycle-viewmodel-2.1.0-runtime.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform lifecycle-viewmodel-2.1.0.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel:2.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for EnumerateClassesTransform: C:\Users\marce.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\0f281f39f7f929407d14ee241c94da2d\lifecycle-viewmodel-2.1.0-runtime.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform lifecycle-runtime-2.1.0.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for EnumerateClassesTransform: C:\Users\marce.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\f81712eaa92db0db50d355012300e724\lifecycle-runtime-2.1.0-runtime.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform lifecycle-runtime-2.1.0.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for EnumerateClassesTransform: C:\Users\marce.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\f81712eaa92db0db50d355012300e724\lifecycle-runtime-2.1.0-runtime.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform lifecycle-runtime-2.1.0.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime:2.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for EnumerateClassesTransform: C:\Users\marce.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\f81712eaa92db0db50d355012300e724\lifecycle-runtime-2.1.0-runtime.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform savedstate-1.0.0.aar (androidx.savedstate:savedstate:1.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for EnumerateClassesTransform: C:\Users\marce.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\350d32b9b21d6bd2ede30c8c14cc8f7f\jetified-savedstate-1.0.0-runtime.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform lifecycle-livedata-2.0.0.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for EnumerateClassesTransform: C:\Users\marce.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\6a8deb74ba0c065e736bea4547f22268\lifecycle-livedata-2.0.0-runtime.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform lifecycle-livedata-2.0.0.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata:2.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for EnumerateClassesTransform: C:\Users\marce.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\6a8deb74ba0c065e736bea4547f22268\lifecycle-livedata-2.0.0-runtime.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform lifecycle-livedata-core-2.0.0.aar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-core:2.0.0) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for EnumerateClassesTransform: C:\Users\marce.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\d9e3d1d2570ed0fedc6413811e25ec74\lifecycle-livedata-core-2.0.0-runtime.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform core-common-2.1.0.jar (androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for EnumerateClassesTransform: C:\Users\marce.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.arch.core\core-common\2.1.0\b3152fc64428c9354344bd89848ecddc09b6f07e\core-common-2.1.0.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform lifecycle-common-2.1.0.jar (androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common:2.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for EnumerateClassesTransform: C:\Users\marce.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.lifecycle\lifecycle-common\2.1.0\c67e7807d9cd6c329b9d0218b2ec4e505dd340b7\lifecycle-common-2.1.0.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:
> Failed to transform annotation-1.1.0.jar (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0) to match attributes {artifactType=enumerated-runtime-classes, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for EnumerateClassesTransform: C:\Users\marce.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\androidx.annotation\annotation\1.1.0\e3a6fb2f40e3a3842e6b7472628ba4ce416ea4c8\annotation-1.1.0.jar.
> > Cannot parse result path string:

Comment: maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36990054/android-studio-resolving-duplicate-classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally fixed it.

I've noticed that in gradle cache I had very old files 2 years+, so why not to delete them?

This is what I did

1. Close Android Studio
2. Deleted manually everything from gradle cache, in my case it was C:\Users\marce\.gradle\caches .
3. Reboot the PC, just to be 101% sure that everything was wiped from cache :)
4. Started Android Studio

And everything started to work again.