# why it is showing error ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I was making an android pdf view app so I added  implementation

`com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.8.2`

In build.gradle but it is displaying an error.

the error message is below

[image: error message screenshot]

Comment: Will [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36990054/android-studio-resolving-duplicate-classes) resolve your problem?

Comment: Its better to not upload images for errors. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question.

Comment: Because you use androidx and support libraries together