# How to resolve duplicate classes in Android Studio

Tags: kotlin, android-studio, debugging, gradle, build.gradle

I was trying to run my app on target device and gradle build was failing because of duplicate classes.
I've done the invalidate caches and restart already.
:app is currently compiled against android-32.

```
  Recommended action: Update this project to use a newer compileSdkVersion
  of at least 33, for example 33.
```

I was getting this error before and changed the targetSdk and compileSdk from 32 to 33 for both and the rest of the errors followed

Gradle file

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}
android {
    namespace 'com.example.quizapp'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.quizapp"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

Error: `Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'. > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable > Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.7.20) Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations found in modules kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.20 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.20)`

Comment: Check this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36991200/8644685).
Also you can try adding this parameter `android.enableJetifier=true` in **gradle.properties**